# What is this syntax? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

In this question here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11
Showing an implementation of a delegate in c++, what is this syntax:

```
template<class R, class ...A>
 class delegate<R (A...)> // <--- Argument wrapping of some kind?
```

Does this become a different type? I have never seen this used before, so I can't really parse what its supposed to do.

Comment: Looks like a function definition (like `std::function<void(int, int)>`): it takes multiple arguments of types `A` (here `A` is a variadic template parameter) and returns `R`.

Comment: So it becomes a single type of function ptr?

Comment: @user45681 Precisely, the type is function, not pointer to function.

Comment: This is a [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). Class template `delegate` is being specialized for the case where its template argument is a function type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a template specialization for a function.

```
template <class T>
struct func;

template <class R, class... A>
struct func<R (A...)>
{

};
```

Specialization will be called if you instantiate the template with a function signature. For example :

```
func<void(int)> f1;
func<int(int, int)> f2;
```